# Existe diferença entre window.addEventListener e addEventListener?

Tags: javascript

Quando eu uso `addEventListener` é o mesmo que `window.addEventListener` ou existe diferença?

Comment: Até onde eu sei, é questão de referencia, `window` você está se referindo a janela em si. Mas posso estar errado.

Comment: window pega a janela toda, até onde você digita a URL, document você pega o documento somente, o site.

Comment: Voce quer dizer que addEventListener sem o ponto se refere ao document?

Comment: Exatamente, é a mesma coisa de user `document`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nenhuma, são a mesma coisa. É um método de `window` que é disponibilizado no escopo global.

Todos os métodos/propriedades de `window` estão no escopo global e podem ser acedidas via objeto: `window.location.href` ou diretamente `location.href`. São centenas...

Comment: Aonde você acha essas informações mais técnicas de javascript?

Comment: @MoraisVilson podes fazer na consola `console.log(Object.keys(window));` e vais ver todas as propriedades/métodos. Para documentação mais técnica podes sempre recorrer à MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window